# Angular 4, get maps object based on string address

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

Is there a way to pass a string (with an address), and get an object with the return? I've an autocomplete for search inside my db for address, but I need to search in Google Maps also. Is there a method or something to pass the string and get the object (there's no need for use the maps for this). I'm using angular 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have made their Place Auto-complete API public. You can access it [here,](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete?csw=1) for instructions on how to build appropriate query strings and how to integrate it properly with your system. The docs are very helpful!

If you use this API with Angulars [HTTPClients](https://angular.io/guide/http) GET method, Googles API will return a JSON object with all of the related information about the location.

Comment: Wow. I hadn't thought of this approach. I think this will do. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting this message on my request:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3005' is therefore not allowed access.

The response status is 200, but don't have any content

Comment: Google place Auto Complete doesn’t enable CORS intentionally, so you need to load the API script vas per the docs. Are you sure that you’re importing the API with the unique that Google provide?